# how to parse complexe XML structure using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have some xml that consists of the following structure

```
<Succession SuccessionID= ....>
    <LinkedSuccession>
        <Succession SuccessionID= ..../> // multiple possible
    </LinkedSuccession>
    <SUF>
        <SeeAlsoSuccession>
            <Succession SuccessionID= ..../> // multiple possible
        </SeeAlsoSuccession>
    </SUF>
    <Plugins>
        <Plugin PluginIdent= ..../> // multiple possible
    </Plugins>
    <Card>
        <Actives>  // multiple possible
            <Active activeNo= ....>  // multiple possible
                <Machs>
                    <Mach Mach= ...../>  // multiple possible
                </Machs>
            </Active>
        </Actives>
    </Card>
</Succession>
```

I would like to know how in the heck to parse this using NSXMLParser I know the two methods

```
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    //..??
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    //..??


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Paser Error = %@", parseError);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"A parsing failure occurred." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
 //..
}
```

normally I would use something like this to access each element, but because of the strucutre of this xml file this dosnt work properly, as when it reads Succession, if just overwrites what ever value with the last one read.

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Succession"]) {
```

etc, however the structure of this XML file is too much for me to handle.. I am hoping to get some help on how to read this xml file using NSXMLParser.

Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: sorry their are elements but i didnt want to add them as there are like 30 + for each that I am dealing with.. will fix the typo now.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to simple have some class property to keep track of whether you're inside a `LinkedSuccession` or a `SeeAlsoSuccession` or neither, and that way, when you encounter a `Succession` element, you'll know if your in one of those two sub element arrays, or whether you're dealing with a top level `Succession` entry, and act accordingly.

---

While there are simple approaches to your problem, as suggested above, I might suggestion two additional possible `NSXMLParser` implementations that might help you tackle your challenge. The first is a block-based implementation of `NSXMLParser` [available on GitHub](https://github.com/robertmryan/xmlblockparser). To use it with your XML sample (in which all of your data appears to be in the attributes of XML tags, you'd just supply a `beginElementBlock`, but in the sample code, I provided, I also illustrated how you'd supply a `endElementBlock`, too). Anyway, with your sample XML, you'd do something like so:

```
XMLBlockParser *parser = [[XMLBlockParser alloc] initWithData:data];

// handler for the parsing of the start of an element, often useful for parsing the attributes included within
// that opening element tag

parser.beginElementBlock = ^(NSArray *elementNames, NSDictionary *attributeDict) {
    NSString *elementName = [elementNames lastObject];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Succession"])
    {
        if ([elementNames count] == 1)
        {
            // top level "Succession": create an object

            self.currentObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [self.currentObject setObject:attributeDict[@"SuccessionID"] forKey:@"SuccessionID"];
            [self.objects addObject:self.currentObject];
        }
        else
        {
            // "Succession" in either "LinkedSuccession" or "SeeAlsoSuccession"

            // let's find the array "LinkedSuccession" or "SeeAlsoSuccession" objects

            NSString *container = elementNames[[elementNames count] - 2];
            NSMutableArray *array = self.currentObject[container];
            if (!array)
            {
                // if not found, then let's create it and add it to our currentObject

                array = [NSMutableArray array];
                self.currentObject[container] = array;
            }

            // how add the attributeDict value

            [array addObject:attributeDict[@"SuccessionID"]];
        }
    }
};

[parser parse];
```

Another approach would be to use a `NSXMLParser` that simply parses the entire XML into some nested tree structure, such as [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/robertmryan/xml-node-parser). For this, you don't have to write any application-specific code for parsing the XML, but you also end up with something a little more complicated than a standard `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`.

You have a number of possible approaches. I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay Im going to investigate this some more.. and any other possible solutions given.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I've updated my answer with some code samples and links to sample projects on github.

Answer (score 0):

How you handle this XML is going to greatly depend on how robust your data model is. If you start using some NSMutableDictionaries to commit your data, specifically the ones where you may have multiple instance of the same element, bundled with a custom data class I think you'll be better off. The key to not stepping all over yourself with that duplicate data is to leverage didEndElement as your trigger to commit that element into whatever your parent data class is before you spawn another element with the same name.

Comment: okay thanks.. I will look into what you have suggested. I need to figure out how to utilize didEndElement better.

Comment: I can offer up some code samples I've used later in the morning. The biggest trip-up point I can see is what was previously called out: the fact you have duplicate-named elements may mess with your parsing.

Comment: Do you own the XML creation or are you parsing through someone else's data model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind that there are really two ways to use NSXMLParser
Searching
Building a data structure

These are not so bad if you know in advance the structure or schema you are going to deal with. 
If you don't know, it's more work, but the parser gives you two important methods along the way lineNumber and columnNumber

You can use these to your advantage. 
Basically, the strategy you can adopt when dealing with an unknown XML structure is to do a dry run or pre parse. 
In that, track the total columns and lines per column or elements or comments, etc. 
it can take some trial and error to get used to. 
But basically you probe the structure of the XML then you have some idea for subsequent rounds what you can work with.

An advantage to pre parsing is that it can be a lot fast. It also makes subsequent parse ops easier and faster.

The trap is trying to do it all in one parse op when you don't know what your receiving exactly and it's not small.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode that may help:

```
NSMutableArray *linkedSuccessionIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *seeAlsoSuccessionIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
BOOL isInLinkedSuccession = NO;
BOOL isInSeeAlsoSuccession = NO;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"LinkedSuccession"])
    {
        isInLinkedSuccession = YES;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SeeAlsoSuccession"])
    {
        isInSeeAlsoSuccession = YES;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Succession"])
    {
        if (isInLinkedSuccession)
        {
            [linkedSuccessionIDs addObject:[attributeDict[@"SuccessionID"]]];
        }
        else if (isInSeeAlsoSuccession)
        {
            [seeAlsoSuccessionIDs addObject:[attributeDict[@"SuccessionID"]]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"LinkedSuccession"])
    {
        isInLinkedSuccession = NO;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SeeAlsoSuccession"])
    {
        isInSeeAlsoSuccession = NO;
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [self processLinkedSuccessionIDs:linkedSuccessionIDs];
    [self processSeeAlsoSuccessionIDs:seeAlsoSuccessionIDs];
}
```

Comment: will this work if there are multiple entries of SeriesID under linkedSuccesssion?

Comment: The code as written will add each one to an array. But I assume you won't want to use this code exactly as-is; it is intended simply to illustrate one possible way to handle elements with the same name.